# Apex Result Is Not Fullscreen (maybe region/breadcrumbs issue)

Tags: sql, oracle, breadcrumbs, region, lov

Does anyone know why my result for cascading LOV is not showing full screen?

[http://i.imgur.com/QIp0YV4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9R3M.png)

As you can see, there is a line in the middle of the page. I have tried several ways to get it set to fullscreen but was unable to.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to change the template under report.